# how to take only categories for x-axis and remove unwanted scaling in Highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

I want create a bar line graphs with navigator,range selector, y axis from both side and graph sector. I implement it using `Highcharts.Chart()` but it's x-axis not comes properly. when i create x-axis properly after change categories to ["2017-2-3'] then range selector goes to 1970 (default value) so i convert date to milliseconds. Now in the x-axis have unwanted values. I want to show only x-axis values which shows in category array. currently 1m,3m,6m not worked i think it happen because of this x-axis issue.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m05sgk3j/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var categories = [1551420000000,1549000800000,1546322400000,1543644000000,1541052000000, 1538373600000, 1535781600000,1533103200000, 1530424800000, 1527832800000, 1525154400000, 1522562400000, 1519884000000, 1517464800000,1514786400000]; 

    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'In March 2019, the average CT_HOURS is 10.55 hours.'
        },
         rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'millisecond',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'millisecond',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            }, {
                type: 'millisecond',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 4,
             inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
            inputEditDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d' 
        }, 
        navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            xAxis: {
                tickInterval: 15,
                labels: {
                   /* formatter: function() {
                        return categories[this.pos]
                    } */
                }
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
         xAxis: {


           // categories: categories,
             type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval : 2,
          // tickInterval: {_tickInterval},
                /* labels: {
                         step:10
                       }, */
            /* maxZoom: 30 * 24 * 3600000, */
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                    day: '%Y-%m'
                } 
           // crosshair: true,
           // minRange: 1
        }, 
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}h',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AVERAGE CT_HOURS',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'REQUEST COUNT',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        series: [{
            name: 'REQUEST COUNT',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [
                [1551420000000, 49.9],
                [1549000800000, 71.5],
                [1546322400000, 106.4],
                [1543644000000, 129.2],
                [1541052000000, 144.0],
                [1538373600000, 176.0],
                [1535781600000, 135.6],
                [1533103200000, 148.5],
                [1530424800000, 49.9],
                [1527832800000, 71.5],
                [1525154400000, 106.4],
                [1522562400000, 129.2],
                [1519884000000, 144.0],
                [1517464800000, 176.0],
                [1514786400000, 135.6]
            ],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        }, {
            name: 'AVERAGE CT_HOURS',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [[1551420000000, 56.6],
                [1549000800000, 46.3],
                [1546322400000, 32.8],
                [1543644000000, 43.4],
                [1541052000000, 40.8],
                [1538373600000, 43.0],
                [1535781600000, 43.1],
                [1533103200000, 44.6],
                [1530424800000, 45.7],
                [1527832800000, 27.8],
                [1525154400000, 39.9],
                [1522562400000, 29.3],
                [1519884000000, 27.9],
                [1517464800000, 27.4],
                [1514786400000, 17.6]],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'h'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the `tickInterval` for the `xAxis`

```
//tickInterval : 2,
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/vjmxgfas/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have unsorted data. If you want to invert your data, use `reversed` option.

Also, the `rangeSelector` and the `tickInterval` are wrong. If you use `datetime` axis, then the basic unit is one millisecond.

However, to show dates only from the `categories` array, use the `tickPositions` option and `formatter` function for labels:

```
    xAxis: {
        reversed: true,
        minRange: 1,
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPositions: categories,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m', this.value);
            }
        }
    },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a6Lphq4k/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.reversed

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Answer (score 0):

(1) First always make sure that you are injecting timestamps in your categories, and formatting them in :

(1-1) xAxis.labels.formatter function [for x axis labels]

(1-2) navigator.xAxis.labels.formatter function [for navigation labels format)

(2) Second make sure that you are clearing your (xAxis.categories) if you push data into  it. because highcharts don't sort your array. if you just assign new array that's ok.

(3) **Note :** Based on values on your categories array, navigation gets some values like xAxis min and xAxis Max. when you change your data these values remain and that's why your navigation collapses. so when changing data make sure to update. you can use 0 for minimum of navigator and categories.length for maximum value of navigator.
you can access updated values also in dataMin and dataMax.

Hope this answer help you.